# Is it possible to use a file for build configurations in TeamCity like TravisCI?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity

One great feature of TravisCI is the ability to add a [configuration file](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started/#Step-three%3A-Add-.travis.yml-file-to-your-repository) to your repository which describes how Travis should run your build. Is something similar possible with TeamCity?

I've done some pretty heavy configuration for *enterprise* TeamCity servers so I'm fairly well versed in it, but I've never seen or heard of this type of configuration and so far as I can tell it's not in the docs. I'd be okay with a plugin as well, assuming it's stable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this feature was requested some time ago and is being tested in a newer version of TC.

Full discussion: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-2806

Relevant comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-2806#comment=27-781368

Comment: Seems more for history than a way to implement build instructions by hand or to include them in the repo with the source code being tested. Curious if anyone has done more with this feature

Answer (score 0):

Try out EAP, this feature is already there.

EAP is currently free http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/TeamCity+EAP+(Latest)